# Wygwam Link List - Hide Hidden Enteries

Tags: wygwam

We have an instance of wygwam.

When the user clicks the link button a list of all entries comes up for the user to choose from.

This list contains both open and closed entries, is there a way to hide the closed enteries and only allow linking to open  entries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke to the makers of the plugin and they confirmed that this is not currently possible and have logged it as a feature request.